# How to determine if a script has already been injected into the document from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension and using the following code to inject the script from my content js.

```
function appendScript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
script.textContent = "window.alert = function(msg) { stopOperation = true; var evt=document.createEvent('CustomEvent'); evt.initCustomEvent('StopOperation', true, true, ''); document.dispatchEvent(evt); return true; }; ";
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

How do I make sure that the above script is injected only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an ID to it, then before injecting check if it already exists, and, if so, do not inject it:

Here is a sample:

```
function appendScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = "my-extension-script";
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = "window.alert = function(msg) { stopOperation = true; var evt=document.createEvent('CustomEvent'); evt.initCustomEvent('StopOperation', true, true, ''); document.dispatchEvent(evt); return true; }; ";
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}

var no_script = !document.getElementById("my-extension-script");

if (no_script) appendScript();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set an attribute with something specific to your application (such as your plugin ID), and check for that element before attempting to add your script.