# Load external JS to be available in <script setup> in Vue 3 component

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, external

I am attempting to implement a [tokenized payment form](https://sandbox.2apgateway.com/docs/tokenizer/#overview) in my Vue3/InertiaJS/Laravel app, and am unable to get the external script loaded so that it is available in the `<script setup>` to define a value and attach it to a DOM element. Per the docs, I am doing this

```
<script setup> 
        const tokenizerScript = document.createElement("script");
        tokenizerScript.setAttribute(
            "src",
            "https://app.2apgateway.com/tokenizer/tokenizer.js"
        );
        tokenizerScript.setAttribute(
            'language',
            'javascript'
        )
        document.head.appendChild(tokenizerScript);

        const tokenizer = new Tokenizer({
            url: apiUrl, 
            apikey: publicApiKey,
            container: '#container', 
            // Callback after submission request has been made
            submission: (resp) => { // Figure out what response you got back
                switch(resp.status) {
                    case 'success':
                        // Successful submission
                        console.log(resp.token)
                        Inertia.post(`/users/${props.user.id}/dues/submit-online-payment`, {
                            token: resp.token
                        })
                        break;
                    case 'error':
                        // Encountered an error while performing submission
                        console.log(resp.msg)
                        break;
                    case 'validation':
                        // Encountered form validation specific errors
                        console.log(resp.invalid)
                        break;
                }
            }
        })
</script>

<template>
    <div id="container" />
</template>
```

No matter how I do it, whether this way, or using `<link rel="prefetch">`, or trying to load it in the `onMounted` or `onBeforeMount` hooks, I get an error that `Tokenizer is not defined.` Often it will work if I go back to the previous page using the browser back button and come back, but not always

How can I get this script loaded so that when I call it in `<script setup>`, it is fully available?

**UPDATE:** Per Marc's suggestion below, I edited the code like this

```
    function doTokenize() {
        const tokenizer = new Tokenizer({
            url: apiUrl, // Optional - Only needed if domain is different than the one your on, example: localhost
            apikey: publicApiKey,
            container: '#container', // Make sure that this "container" is the same as the id of the div container you referenced above.
            // Callback after submission request has been made
            submission: (resp) => { // Figure out what response you got back
                switch (resp.status) {
                    case 'success':
                        // Successful submission
                        console.log(resp.token)
                        Inertia.post(`/users/${props.user.id}/dues/submit-online-payment`, {
                            token: resp.token
                        })
                        break;
                    case 'error':
                        // Encountered an error while performing submission
                        console.log(resp.msg)
                        break;
                    case 'validation':
                        // Encountered form validation specific errors
                        console.log(resp.invalid)
                        break;
                }
            }
        })
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        // debugger;
        const tokenizerScript = document.createElement("script");
        tokenizerScript.setAttribute(
            "src",
            "https://app.2apgateway.com/tokenizer/tokenizer.js"
        );
        tokenizerScript.setAttribute(
            'language',
            'javascript'
        )

        tokenizerScript.defer = true

        tokenizerScript.onload = () => {
            doTokenize()
        }
        document.head.appendChild(tokenizerScript);
    })

<template>
    <div class="mb-6 max-w-2xl">
        <h2 class="font-bold text-2xl">Pay Online Form</h2>

        <p>Amount to be charged: <span class="font-bold">${{ total }}</span></p>

        <div class="mt-4" id="container"></div>

        <button class="mt-4 px-4 py-2 bg-indigo-600 text-white rounded-md ml-2"
                @click="tokenizer.submit()"
        >
            Submit Payment
        </button>

    </div>
</template>
```

and the form loads right away and without error, which is great. However, when clicking on my `Submit Payment` button, I get this error now:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "submit", _ctx.tokenizer is undefined
```

**FIX** I finally realized that the issue was a simple matter of scope; I was defining `tokenizer` inside a function, but it wasn't making it available externally. Once I made this change:

```
let tokenizer = {};

    function doTokenize() {
        tokenizer = new Tokenizer({
            url: apiUrl, // Optional - Only needed if domain is different than the one your on, example: localhost
            apikey: publicApiKey,
            container: '#container', // Make sure that this "container" is the same as the id of the div container you referenced above.
            // Callback after submission request has been made
            submission: (resp) => { // Figure out what response you got back
                switch (resp.status) {
                    case 'success':
                        // Successful submission
                        console.log(resp.token)
                        Inertia.post(`/users/${props.user.id}/dues/submit-online-payment`, {
                            token: resp.token
                        })
                        break;
                    case 'error':
                        // Encountered an error while performing submission
                        console.log(resp.msg)
                        break;
                    case 'validation':
                        // Encountered form validation specific errors
                        console.log(resp.invalid)
                        break;
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know when the script is ready in order to use the code it provides and you may need to do this in `onMounted` in theory because you can only append when the DOM exists to append it to.

---

Before you append `tokenizerScript` to the document, you need to consider if this has been ran before and if the script is already loaded, check out this post on how to prevent duplication (ignore the fact its about a chrome extension):

[How to determine if a script has already been injected into the document from Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368874/how-to-determine-if-a-script-has-already-been-injected-into-the-document-from-ch)

---

You should put tokenizer in its own method `(funciton doTokenize() { ... new Tokenizer() ... })` that you can call if the script is already loaded or defer calling it after it has loaded via a  callback.

To wait for `tokenizer.js` to be loaded you should register an `onload` callback function before doing `appendChild(tokenizerScript)`.

```js
tokenizerScript.defer = true

tokenizerScript.onload = () => {
  doTokenize()
}

document.head.appendChild(tokenizerScript);
```

---

## Race condition

I think this is a race condition where `@click="tokenizer.submit()"` will be rendered before the script is loaded, it starts broken and remains broken.

You need to prevent rendering of the content in the template so it does not try to bind a method that does not yet exist.

You could use an async setup approach that would offer a very clean setup you load the script using Promise so you can await its completion using the Suspense feature in Vue 3.3.4+ or you can use a very quick and easy ready state:

```js
<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue'

const ready = ref(false)

let tokenizer = null // You var needs to be declared before onMounted

function doTokenize() {

  tokenizer = new Tokenizer({...})

  // Set ready to true in doTokenize.
  // if you do check if the script is already loaded and 
  // call this function outside of onload, they you want
  // the ready state to be true immediately.
  ready.value = true

}

onMounted(() => {

  ...

}
</script>


<template>

  <div class="mb-6 max-w-2xl">

    <template v-if="ready">

      <h2 class="font-bold text-2xl">Pay Online Form</h2>

      <p>Amount to be charged: <span class="font-bold">${{ total }}</span></p>

      <div class="mt-4" id="container"></div>

      <button class="mt-4 px-4 py-2 bg-indigo-600 text-white rounded-md ml-2"
        @click="tokenizer.submit()">
            Submit Payment
      </button>

    </template>

    <template v-else>
      Loading...
    </template>

  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: So I did that, and it loads the form just fine. However, when I click on the Submit button, I get an error about `can't access property "submit", _ctx.tokenizer is undefined`. I've verified that the external script is loaded, and the fact that the form is displayed tells me it is. What else am I missing?

Comment: I updated my answer to address rendering race condition.

Comment: Also here is a possible solution on how to check if the tokenizer script is already loaded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368874/how-to-determine-if-a-script-has-already-been-injected-into-the-document-from-ch

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using mounted() function in your code.

```
<script>
  export default {
    
    mounted() {
      let tokenizerScript= document.createElement('script')
      tokenizerScript .setAttribute('src', 'https://app.2apgateway.com/tokenizer/tokenizer.js')
      document.head.appendChild(tokenizerScript)
    }

  }
</script>
```